# Assigning a pointer in content of a pointer

Tags: c, pointers, struct, linked-list, return

In the code, we can see that a pointer is assigned in `*new_node` .  But in `C` `*new_node` means content of `new_node`. So, what is the reason for it & why isn't it creating any problem?

```
Node *create_node(int item, Node *next)
{
    Node *new_node = (Node *)malloc(sizeof(Node));      //isn't it receiving the pointer as content of(*new_node) new_node?
    if (new_node == NULL) {
        printf("Error! Could not crate a new Node\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    new_node->data = item;
    new_node->next = next;
}
```

Comment: Wait so what exactly is the problem you are having? Can you rewrite the little text so it makes no sense?

Comment: The `new_node` is assigned to, not `*new_node`. Technically, this is an initialization, which is different from `Node *new_node; *new_node = malloc(sizeof(Node));`, which would make no sense.

Comment: Are you just confused by the use of `Node *new_node = ...` rather than `Node* new-node = ...`? They mean the same thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In an expression `*new_node` means “the object pointed to by `new_node`.” However, `Node *new_node = (Node *)malloc(sizeof(Node));` is a declaration, not an expression statement, and the text `*new_node` in it is not an expression.

The first part of the declaration, `Node *new_node`, says “`new_node` is a pointer to a `Node`.” The second part of the declaration, `= (Node *)malloc(sizeof(Node))`, says “initialize `new_node` to `(Node *)malloc(sizeof(Node))`. The `=` in this is not an assignment, and this is not an assignment expression. It is a syntax used in declarations for specifying an initial value for the object being defined. The object being defined is `new_node`, not `*new_node`.

This is different syntax between declarations and assignments, and you will have to become accustomed to it. `Node *new_node = foo;` initializes `new_node` to `foo`, but `*new_node = foo;` sets `*new_node` to `foo`.

Answer (score 0):

`Node *new_node = (Node *)malloc(sizeof(Node));`

This allocates new dynamic memory for new element of Node struct. And base address of the allocated memory is stored in new_node.

Now, new_node points to a new memory but that memory is empty/garbage. It doesn't contain any useful information about the node. So we need to fill the necessary information it that structure to make it useful.

```
`new_node->data = item;`
 new_node->next = next;
```

These lines copy the data to the allocated memory of new node and link the new node with other nodes.

NOTE: Your code snippet doesn't have return statement.